# PHP 5.5 - Empty $_POST fields with ISO-8859-1 and intl. characters

Tags: php, forms, post, character-encoding

I'm upgrading from PHP 5.2 to 5.5 and when I submit a form field with international characters, like "Häst", the entire field is null in $_POST. All other $_POST fields are as they should.

If I view the Chrome inspector on the page after the post, it says (unable to decode value) in the headers form data for this field. If I click "View URL encoded" in there it shows "H%E4st", so there is something in the field, but it just doesn't show up.

I have this encoding in the `<head>` of the page:

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<meta content="iso-8859-1" http-equiv="encoding">
```

I tried to make a completely empty PHP page with the same headers, and just a submit form field, and the $_POST works as it should.

So there's something wrong with my code, but even if i check $_POST['fieldname'] in the top of  index.php, it's still empty, so I suspect something on the page with the form is sending it through POST with the wrong encoding. Is there any more ways to set the encoding of the form that I missed?

If I change the meta tags above to UTF8, everything works, except everything else on the page is garbled, since my db is latin1/iso-8859-1, so I need it to work with this charset. I don't use htmlspecialchars or anything, just a simple POST.

What should I look for? Or do I need to convert my entire DB to utf8 to make this work?